# Session variables are unset

Tags: php

I'm trying to store a lot of POST data in a php session. The data appears to be saved without any problem, but when I try to access the data on the next page load, it is unset. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. This is the minimum working example that I can make:

## index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['roles'] = $_POST['ext_roles'];
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

## session.php

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

When I make a POST to `index.php`, the data is shown as expected:

```
/var/www/default/index.php:4:
array (size=1)
  'roles' => string '00000000000000000' (length=17)
```

but when I load `session.php`, I get this:

```
/var/www/default/session.php:3:
array (size=1)
  'roles' => null
```

It doesn't happen with all data either, just the data that I actually care about. If I just use postman to submit random POST data, it works just as expected, but the data that comes into the initial POST from the external source that I'm trying to save is consistently set to null or an empty array. I am at a complete loss here.

here is the form data that I'm trying to persist with the session:

## form.html

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="oauth_consumer_key" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="oauth_signature_method" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="oauth_timestamp" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="oauth_nonce" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="oauth_version" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="context_id" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="context_label" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="context_title" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="custom_canvas_api_domain" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="custom_canvas_assignment_id" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="custom_canvas_assignment_points_possible" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="custom_canvas_assignment_title" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="custom_canvas_course_id" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="custom_canvas_enrollment_state" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="custom_canvas_user_id" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="custom_canvas_user_login_id" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="ext_ims_lis_basic_outcome_url"
           value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="ext_outcome_data_values_accepted" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="ext_outcome_result_total_score_accepted" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="ext_outcomes_tool_placement_url"
           value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="ext_roles"
           value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="launch_presentation_document_target" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="launch_presentation_locale" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="launch_presentation_return_url"
           value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="lis_course_offering_sourcedid" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="lis_outcome_service_url"
           value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="lis_person_contact_email_primary" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="lis_person_name_family" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="lis_person_name_full" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="lis_person_name_given" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="lis_person_sourcedid" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="lti_message_type" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="lti_version" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="oauth_callback" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="resource_link_id" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="resource_link_title" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="roles" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="tool_consumer_info_product_family_code" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="tool_consumer_info_version" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="tool_consumer_instance_contact_email" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="tool_consumer_instance_guid"
           value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="tool_consumer_instance_name" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="user_image"
           value="00000000000000000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="oauth_signature" value="00000000000000000"/>
    <button type="submit" name="submitButton">Go</button>
</form>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what kind of data is that? the one deleted. give us a sample.

Comment: The one thing I see that can cause this, is the `session_unset()` at the start. It would mean that it is again called on the load of `session.php`, but that can be causing this.

Comment: @Nytrix I have tried with and without `session_unset()`. The real code does not have `session_unset()` in it.

Comment: Man if you want to store that much data in SESSION, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @MertMetin That's not exactly an answer to why the session data is not persistant, though.

Comment: @NateMara It's a strange problem, but to actually solve what's going on we'll need a lot of data. Is there not another way of doing what you want to do? It seems pretty unregular to save that much data into a session...

Comment: @MertMetin @Nytrix: I actually only want to store the `ext_roles` field. It is erased just the same as the huge block of data, I was just providing this as a minimum example of the behavior.

Comment: That's right. It was a suggestion. which data above is deleted in Session?

Comment: @NateMara In that case, why not just first get that value out of there and put that into the session...? In that case it will be a lot more effecient. If that is also losing the data, we'll need to look into it more.

Comment: @Nytrix: just edited with a more accurate example index.php, behavior is still present even if I just get the single string.

Comment: ext_roles is too big ? How many characters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change:

```
$_SESSION['post-data'] = $_POST;
```

into:

```
if ($_POST) $_SESSION['post-data'] = $_POST;
```

Otherwise, post-data will get set to empty array with any $_GET call.

Comment: Haven't tested it, but it looks like it might be the problem.

Comment: This does work actually. Can someone tell me why this works? The data should be stored in the session during the execution of `index.php`, then I don't understand why the fact that it's a post has any significance during the execution of `session.php`.

Comment: if this "works" something elses unshown to us is going on

Comment: index.php definitely gets called again after posting the data.